# Wavelet modulation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wavelet, modulation

I need to plot the waveform for the following expression:-

[image: expression].

I don't understand how to define a wavelet as a function of time 't' (where 't' I will define)?

How do I scale and translate a wavelet?

```
[phi,psi,xval] = wavefun('db4',10);  %extracting the psi function from db4
[a,s]=size(psi);            %extracting the number of samples.
yc(t,1)= yc(t,1)+abs(dataMod(x,1))*dataMod(x,1)*(2^m)*psi(1,(10*(2^m)*t-k));
```

where I am storing my modulated signal in `yc`, (all this is inside loops), and `dataMod` is an array of QAM symbols.

But I am getting a non nonsensical plot as follows:-

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

The 't' is shown in the 'xval' part, the xval represents the compact support, and xval = 2*N -1, here N = 4 (db4), so just substitute 'xval' with 't', and that should work.